# Delete existing file and create/write data into same file using TransformerFactory within a loop

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I want to transform the input.XML file with XSL and **overwrite** the output.XML file in a loop so that I get the final output.XML file.

I am able to do this, however instead of **overwriting** the output.XML file, it's **appending** the same file with all iteration data of loop.

To resolve this issue, I tried to delete the existing output.XML file in loop only just before transforming the input.XML file with XSL, but getting error -

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Output.xml: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

So, I'm NOT able to delete the existing file also not able to overwrite the output.xml file.

Can anyone help on this pls.
I believe resolving any one of these issue should help out.

Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    
    try {
        
        Double currentValue = 1.0;
        
        String inputXMLPath = "C:/MySystem/Input.xml";
        
        String outputXMLPath = "C:/MySystem/Output.xml";
        
        StreamSource inputStream = new StreamSource(inputXMLPath);
        
        FileOutputStream opStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputXMLPath));
        
        while (currentValue != 7.0) {
            String xslPath = "C:/MySystem/input.xsl";
            Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(outputXMLPath);
            Files.delete(path);
            
            performTransformation(xslPath, inputStream, opStream, outputXMLPath);
            StreamSource secondStream = new StreamSource(outputXMLPath);
            inputStream = secondStream;
            currentValue++;
            opStream.flush();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void performTransformation(String xslPath, StreamSource inputStream, FileOutputStream opStream,
        String outputXMLPath) throws Exception {        
    
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = null;
    transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslPath));
    transformer.transform(inputStream, new StreamResult(opStream));
    opStream.flush();
}
```

Comment: You are not properly closing the output stream (and probably also the input), use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can't edit or delete this file because the input stream is still open, that's why it is still in use if you can close the input stream then delete the XML file and then make a new one it should work no problem.

This should fit your use case assuming the file is always called the same thing.

Also the deleteIfExists(Path) method is useful as it will still delete the file but will not throw an exception if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the file because you haven't closed it. But instead of deleting it, why don't you re-create the file inside the loop, instead of outside it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      *** DELETE THIS LINE ***
    
    try {
        
        Double currentValue = 1.0;
        
        String inputXMLPath = "C:/MySystem/Input.xml";
        
        String outputXMLPath = "C:/MySystem/Output.xml";
        
        StreamSource inputStream = new StreamSource(inputXMLPath);
        
        // *** DANGER! COMPARING DOUBLES IS PRONE TO ERRORS! ***
        while (currentValue != 7.0) {
            // *** USE TRY-WITH-RESOURCES TO ENSURE THE STREAM GETS CLOSED ***
            try (FileOutputStream opStream = new FileOutputStream(outputXMLPath)) {
        
                String xslPath = "C:/MySystem/input.xsl";
            
                performTransformation(xslPath, inputStream, opStream, outputXMLPath);
                StreamSource secondStream = new StreamSource(outputXMLPath);
                inputStream = secondStream;
                currentValue++;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```